# Multi-level UITableView Show

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My problem here is that i have a list of folders, and the folders directory will show on tableview, when user tap on folder(tableview cell)I need to jump into the next level of the folder and the tableview will display its sub files,(notice:not the tree structure,just show all its sub files, i get the folder's next level directory from a server when user tap the folder in cell) .In sub files list ,if user tap on a sub folder I need to show list of its sub files and so on.

my thought is to is create a subclass of UITableViewController that will recreate instances of itself when the user selects a row. put the first instance in a navigationcontroller and use
 [navigationController pushViewController: animated] to push the multi levels one by one.
But i do not know how to override the method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

to achieve my thought. Thanks everyone ,i need your help!

Comment: Are you looking for something like a treeview? Something like, >> Root
>Node1
  >Node1a
    >Node1a1
  >Node1b
    >Node1b1
    >Node1b2
    >Node1b3
>Node2
  >Node2a
    >Node2a1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the basic idea of what you want. Hopefully it gets you started anyway. Definitely read up on UITableViews and look at some sample code online or in a reference book.

```
@interface FileTableViewController <UITableViewController>
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *filenames; // includes dirnames
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *dirNames;
@end

@implementation FileTableViewController

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [filenames count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] dequeueReuseableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    cell.textLabel.text = self.filenames[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *filename = self.filenames[indexPath.row];
    if (self.dirnames containsObject:filename)
    {
        FileTableViewController *subVC = [[FileTableViewController alloc] init];
        subVC.filenames = [self filenamesForSubDir:filename];
        subVC.dirnnames = [self dirnamesForSubDir:filename];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:subVC animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much , Ben !! I will try it. you're damn right,i need read more sample code online.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

1> Just obtain the path of the next directory from didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

2> If you get response then replace the old array of data that is used in your  cellForRowAtIndexPath for displaying the folder/files name with the data in response.

3> reload your table view and the delegates of table view will be called.(change delegate method according to your response).